# Django: get limit of 10 data from specific id as starting point

Tags: django

I wonder how you could do this...
Normally,

```
DjangoObject.objects.all()[:10]
```

gives you limit of 10 data from the latest (if ordering is done in Model layer by recent date)

However, what I want to do is like (below is just an example, not valid Django Syntax):

```
DjangoObject.objects.filter(fromId=primaryKey)[:10]
```

So, here I want to get 10 data from a specific starting point. All I want here is to get 10 data in the middle of the list. Is there an easy way to do this?

I am using MongoDB as data source, so the primary is not incremental.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is what you want:

```
In [1]: from foo.models import Foo
In [2]: Foo.objects.filter(pk__gt=10)
Out[2]: []
```

pk means "Primary Key" and gt means "greater than". You can find it documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#gt):

Comment: You then need to do the [:10] to get the first 10 items.

Comment: I should have mentioned what db im using... I'm using MongoDB, which primary key is the Object Id. I'll give one point for this answer but does not satisfy my question. Thanks!

Comment: Actually the object id of MongoDB is based on the time, so it should also work.